# Encrypted file image access

Tags: security, user-account, encryption, dmg

I have 3 users on a mac os computer:

- Administrator
- user A: Standard Account
- user B: Standard Account

User A should not see User B files. And User B should not see User A files.

User A has an encrypted file image (dmg file) in his home directory.

When User A wants to see this image content, he must double click on the dmg file and type a password.

The image is mount on the system.

But i have a big problem: When this encrypted image is mounted, User B can see the content !

How can i prevent User B to access to this file image content when it is mounted ?

Thanks

Comment: Isn‘t this already answered in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123566/preventing-access-to-mounted-volumes-for-non-admin-users?

Comment: No because i only want to deny access to encrypted volumes and i do not know the names of futures volumes …

Comment: Are the users tech-savvy enough to run a script to mount the DMG?

Comment: No they will mount by double clicking on the file and typing password

Comment: Which filesystem format is used in the DMG?

Comment: Apfs format but i can change

Comment: Can they create a top folder with 0700 permissions within the DMG and put their files into that?

Comment: No but is there a way to change mount path of a dmg ? Thanks

Comment: You can change the mount path if you mount with a script :-)

Comment: You also might be able to have a LaunchDaemon looking for changes in /Volumes and changing access permissions if necessary. But I have no experience with this.

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to remove rw rights on /Volumes ? User B won't be able to put a usb drive but that does not matter. Thanks

Comment: I would change the permissions on the mount point (after the mount).

Comment: I mean changing permanently the permissions of /Volumes. Do you know if it will work ?

Comment: This seems to be something you can try yourself :-)

Comment: In other words is it possible to set default permissions for new mounted volumes ? Thanks

Comment: What is the real problem you want to solve? The encrypted dmg (if it works for you) looks like a solution, not a problem. If you wanted to protect some of A's files from B snooping, you would just use permissions on A's folders. So I assume you want to protect some of A's files from everyone (including the administrator) - in that case give A a flash drive or SSD (optionally encrypted) which they disconnect when not using.

Comment: The problem is dmg or ssd drive content is not protected when it is mounted !  It is only protected when not used/mounted

Comment: Launchd has a `StartOnMount` option which triggers a program/script each time a volume is mounted. You could use this to run a script which looks into /Volumes and changes access permissions to 0700 where needed.